# How to use ValueListenableBuilder and the ValueNotifier on my radio button so when the radio Button is checked,it displays the formfield

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

So i wrapped my formfield in a visble widget to hide and display the textformfield when the radio button is checked but i works fine but the  you somethime have to double click it is want to use ValueListenableBuilder and the ValueNotifier to also archive this.

```
                        
              
Visibility(
                visible: _isVisible,
                child: Container(
                  width: 396,
                  height: 73,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Color(0xff000000).withOpacity(0.08),
                          offset: Offset(0, 2),
                          blurRadius: 6,
                        ),
                      ],
                      color: Color(0xffFAFAFA),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(17)),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 25, 0, 0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      enabled: _character == SingingCharacter.unchecked
                          ? true
                          : false,
                      onSaved: (Value) => print(hello),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: "Proxima Nova",
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                        ),
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xffFAFAFA),
                        ),
                      ),
                      inputFormatters: [
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r"[0-9]+|\s"))
                      ],
                      controller: kiloMeter,
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value != null && value.isEmpty || value != 1000) {
                          return 'Please enter your Kilometer';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: what is `_isVisible` ,Can you provide full widget with  your value notifier

Answer (score 0):

Create a `valueNotifer` with `bool` like

```dart
final ValueNotifier<bool> _visiBilityNotifier = ValueNotifier(false);
```

And usecase will be

```dart
ValueListenableBuilder<bool>(
  valueListenable: _visiBilityNotifier,
  builder: (context, value, child) {
    return value ? Text("VisibleWidgget") : const SizedBox.shrink();
  },
)
```

To update the value use

```dart
_visiBilityNotifier.value  = yourNewValue; //true or false
```

You can direct value(wont refresh UI)

```
_visiBilityNotifier.value
```

Comment: thank a lot.can i use this on a radio button.

Comment: yap, you can , replace `Text` with `TextFormFiled` and on radio button changed, set the value to true when you like to show it

Comment: radio button code ```ListTile(
                            title: const Text('Policy'),
                            leading: Radio<SingingCharacter>(
                              onChanged: (SingingCharacter? isKiloChecked) {
                                setState(() {
                              
                          ),``` so wrap ValueListenableBuilder on this.

Comment: `onChanged: (SingingCharacter? isKiloChecked) {    _visiBilityNotifier.value = isKiloChecked??false;`  BTW, you are already using statefullWidget, you can use that bool as you did on question , like `if(myBool)ShowThisWidget()`